# Multiple Pages vs Single Page with many artboards in Sketch 3?

Tags: sketch-app, artboard

I'm new to the app so just wondering if anyone has experienced performance issues with just using a single page with tons of artboards vs having multiple pages with few artboards.

I'm designing a website and each page of the website will have 3-10 artboards (responsive breakpoints + slight variations and assets). I will have 5 website pages to design so that equals 15 - 50 artboards. Most likely some where in the middle ~30 artboards total in the document.

Should I be just creating a new page in sketch for each page on the website? Or just have one page and all the artboards on that page? I'm thinking multiple pages in sketch as it will be better organized and probably have better performance.

What do you think? Did I miss something hugely important?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to have each website page on one sketch page, putting the responsive designs in artboards. I also do variations on the design in artboards, but I clean this up later. All my assets go on one page together, often grouping them in artboards if needed.

Organisation has never been a problem for me when doing this, nor has performance been an issue. And my pc specs really aren't anything special. I've been working on 31 artboards in one page (needed to make multiple variations of one small design) and as long as you place them together well and *name* them well, I think it's totally fine.

I do however work with mostly low quality placeholders for images when doing this, only the final set gets better quality images.

Comment: What happens when you need to reuse assets on a different file of the same project?

Comment: @John I don't use different files for the same project? I don't see where this question is coming from, 2 years later.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer. So what is the highest number of pages in a single file that you had?

Comment: @John Often 25-30. I try to work with a file per release. We currently use Design System by invision for asset management across files/designers but we're still testing this out.

Comment: If you do Responsive design, would you split those 25-30 pages per different dimensions per file or you would keep different RD designs as artboards inside each page?

Comment: I always have to deliver responsive designs, that's why I use different pages atm. IE a hompage would get an artboard with desktop, artboard for tablet portrait/landscape and phone portrait/landscape all in seperate artboards. If needed I also do extra form/button/hover states in separate artboards within the same page. Those elements will all be symbols so I'd only have to edit/update them once, but my devs like seeing the complete picture.

Comment: That is what I am doing at the moment. Sometimes project with many pages in one file are difficult to handle. Especially if you have new file for different version, it is difficult to locate the change. Having symbols for entire project and different design on one place is also challenging

Answer (score 0):

Multi-pages is definitely the best of the two solutions. The more artboards you have on your page, the more elements Sketch will have to render, especially if you zoom out.
Having too much artboards on a page can also cause an organization problem.

So, my advice : use different pages and when you are good with an artboard version, put the rest on an archive page.